iOS - Resize StackView according to Container view's height
I am developing a complex UI which comprises of multiple parts. So, I have opted to use Container Views. I have a tableView inside the containerView, and containerView is inside a stackView in parent viewController. Entire content in the parent controller is scrollable and must resize according to the content in tableView. Hence I am using a self resizing tableView. Below is the storyboard structure.

Here is the tableView which I am using.
public final class StackTableView: UITableView {

    // MARK: Variable overrides
    override public var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric,
                      height: contentSize.height)
    }
}

Below is the ContainerViewController
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: StackTableView!
    
    let items = [
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "42",
        "Order ID": "87HF349RH",
        "Date" : "23/12/2023",
        "Email": "John@gmail.com",
        "Phone number": "00000-00000",
        "Summary": "Some summary goes here",
        "Another summary": "Another summary goes here"
    ]
}

extension ContainerViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ContainerViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 72
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        var cell : UITableViewCell!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        
        var configuration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        configuration.text = Array(items.keys)[indexPath.row]
        configuration.secondaryText = Array(items.values)[indexPath.row]
        cell.contentConfiguration = configuration
        
        return cell
    }
}

I needed a result where the tableView does not scroll, and rather the entire screen is scrollable according to the setup. But I see that screen has not resized and tableView is scrollable.

But, replacing the containerView with the tableView directly in the storyboard gives me the expected result as below. But I would like to achieve that same result by placing the tableView inside containerView. No idea what I am missing!


not sure if you have good reason, but you should avoid putting table view inside a scroll view, let your table view be parent, and have you sections/rows customized as per your layout requirements.

You have a list of 8 "items" ... is that what you want to use for the table view rows? Or, will you possibly have 80 items? Or 800?

@DonMag Items are dynamic. Here I have added 8 just for the illustration.

@iOS - OK, as Teja said, you should not use a "self-sizing" table view approach. Make the image a table view cell... make the other view a table view cell.. then use a repeating cell for each of the "items." Probably best to make it 3 sections, so you can keep your items array / dictionary Zero-based.
